# Write PCD File from a Topic - Hydro + PCL (Migration)

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm doing a hand gesture recognition project and I am having some troubles with the migration of the PCL data types to ROS Hydro. I started with Hydro + PCL this week so, not all the concepts are really clear for me. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

My problem is to transform the data that come from my passthrough filter **(sensor_msgs/PointCloud2)** to a **pcl::PointCloud pcl::PointXYZRGB**, so I can write the data using the **savePCDFileASCII** function.

My code is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h> //hydro
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h> //hydro
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

ros::Publisher pub;

void
cloud_cb (const pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud_filtered;
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, cloud_filtered);

  //cloud_filtered.header = pcl_conversions::toPCL(input.header); 

  //pcl_conversions::toPCL(input, cloud_filtered);

  pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("test_pcd.pcd", cloud_filtered);

  pub.publish(input);
}

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "pcl_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/passthrough", 1, cloud_cb);

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output", 1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();

  //End Program
  return (0);
}
```

As you guys can see in my code, I tried some transformations after reading the hydro/Migration page, but I couldn't figure it out what i need to do to make my code work.

The error while doing catkin_make is a no matching function because the type error:

```
/home/breil/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp: In function ‘void cloud_cb(const PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr&)’:
/home/breil/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:21:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘fromROSMsg(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>&)’
/home/breil/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:21:41: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:486:8: note: template<class T> void pcl::fromROSMsg(const PointCloud2&, pcl::PointCloud<PointT>&)
```

Thank you very much for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121856/write-pcd-file-from-a-topic---hydro-+-pcl-(migration)/) by [lfelipesv](https://answers.ros.org/users/10721/lfelipesv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-24**:
I think you do not need this to... and fromRosMSG() anymore in hydro. A least for publishing you just put the cloud into the publish method of a sensro_msgs::PointCloud2 publisher and unlike in prev versions it just works. But I dont know the opposite way..

**Comment by [lfelipesv](https://answers.ros.org/users/10721/lfelipesv/) on 2014-01-24**:
Yes Wolf, the publisher is working fine with the type. The problem is to save the PCD File, because I can't use sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 type. The pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII function. So I need to do some transformation before.

int pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII(const string&, const pcl::PointCloud&)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is that you are trying to use `fromROSmsg` using as input a point cloud that is already with namespace pcl. Does `pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII(*input)` work? Another way to make it work could be using a `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` in your callback as input type (`void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)`) and then use the conversion with fromROSmsg. Let me know if it works!

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfelipesv](https://answers.ros.org/users/10721/lfelipesv/) on 2014-01-26**:
Thank you Tirjen! It worked using sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 =)